# convert from ImageMagick works on command line but not from localhost

Tags: imagemagick

I am able to do use the ImageMagick convert function on the command line with no problems:

```
/usr/local/magick/bin/convert a.pdf b.png
```

I then put it in a one-line PHP file named **testconvert.php**:

```
system("/usr/local/magick/bin/convert a.pdf b.png", $code);
```

and it works fine as a command line call from PHP:

```
php testconvert.php
```

But, when I run the script from my browser on localhost:

```
http://localhost/~me/testconvert.php
```

I get the error:

> convert: no images defined `b.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3253

I found a lot of folks who have encountered similar problems and fixes ranged from using the absolute path for the files (didn't help) to installing ghostscript (didn't help, either).  I'm going a bit gaga with this.  Would anyone have any thoughts about what I can possibly try?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't sort out the issue.  I've explained in a comment to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `system()` line to:

```
system("pwd");
```

and you will see which directory your script is running in.

Comment: The output is what I expect, which is the directory that has the script - but I'm not sure how that helps me.  When I do a direct command line execution of the script (as described in the posting), it also runs it in the directory.  The directory has 777 permission set so it shouldn't be a write error from the server call.

Comment: @hitlad Ok, try converting a PNG file to another PNG file and then you will not be dependent on `ghostscript` and you will see if that works. Also, try adding `-verbose` after `convert` and you will see what it is trying to do.

Comment: It did that conversion without a problem.  When I was trying to follow the ghostscript suggestion from another thread, I had both installed ghostscript and found it (version 9.10) as part of the existing search path.  Maybe the path is working for me shell but is not in the PHP search path?

Comment: Ah, thanks for that!  Now...how to change the PHP search path...It seems like set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $gspath); again, works in the shell but not as a script through a browser.  Or, rather, the new include path does include the path to gs but, which I do a system('which gs') it still turns up null.